# Types supported by Postgresql enum types

Tags: postgresql, enums

As far as I see the [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-enum.html) documentation on enum types only says:

> Enumerated (enum) types are data types that comprise a static, ordered set of values.

So I tried the following:
`create type foo as enum (1, 2, 3);`, but got

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
>
> Position: 26

My assumption is that enums only support `text` as value, but I don't really see this in the documentation. Can someone confirm my assumption? And if it is in the documentation please point me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum labels have to be string constants.

This is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html):

> ```
> CREATE TYPE name AS ENUM
>    ( [ 'label' [, ... ] ] )
> ```

Single quotes imply a string constant.

Answer (score -1):

They aren't text - they are enumerated values.

Different enum types aren't comparable either - they are different types.

```
=> CREATE TYPE traffic_light AS enum ('red', 'yellow', 'green');
CREATE TYPE
=> CREATE TYPE rainbow AS enum ('red', 'yellow', 'green');
CREATE TYPE
=> SELECT traffic_light 'red' = rainbow 'red';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: traffic_light = rainbow
LINE 1: SELECT traffic_light 'red' = rainbow 'red';
                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Now, a lot of C-derived programming languages have enums as named identifiers for integers, but they are an actual type here.

You *do* enter literal enum values by quoting them, like almost every type apart from numbers and booleans. That's obviously necessary if you want enumerated values to consist of something other than digits. But they aren't `text`.

Comment: What is a value? How can I have an enum that has the value ```interval '60 second'```? For me ```interval '60 second'``` is a value of the type ```duration```.

Comment: Well, it is a value of type "interval" fairly obviously, but yes. An enum value that happened to be spelt `'60 second'` is completely unrelated - you cannot treat it like an interval (multiply it by an integer or truncate it to a number of minutes for example).